# padding not working in fluid container in bootstarp 4.5 v

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<body>

  <section id="title">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">TinDog</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item"></li>
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>

            <li class="nav-item"></li>
            <a class="nav-link" href="">pricing</a>

            <li class="nav-item"></li>
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>

          </ul>
        </div>

      </nav>
      <!-- Title -->

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6  col-md-12">
          <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
          <button type="button">Download</button>
          <button type="button">Download</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6  col-md-12">
          <img src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

--------css--------------------------------------------

```
#title{
  background-color:#ff4c68;
}
h1{
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-size: 3rem;
line-height: 1.5;
}
.container-fluid{
padding:200px;
}
```

---

padding is not working in bootstrap v 4.5 in fluid containers all style sheets are linked properly but why padding is not getting applied? also if i write padding left or right still it do not work?

Comment: Do you want margin or padding? How would we know if it's "working"?

Comment: I want padding if it would be working my full container will shift and we can also view it using pesticide...

Comment: add padding:200px !important;

Comment: yes it works but can you explain logic behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a padding then you can simply do

```
.container-fluid{
padding: 200px !important;
}
```

or give the `div` an id and then specify the padding without `!important`.

Comment: yes it worked help is appreciated but can you explain logic behind this?

Comment: @DivyangBhamat, `!important` overrides the existing rule and gives priority to the current one.

Comment: great help is appreciated

Comment: and an id selector will override a class selector(but not !important)